# why call the output port of a element to "src pad" in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I wonder the strange name policy of gstreamer. in a pipeline, the `sink pad` is actually a input port and the `src pad` is a output port, but the `sink element` is the  end element, `src element` is the start element? I think it is wired to understand, could anyone show me more details.

Answer (score 0):

The "src pad" might be an output *for that block* but it can also be seen as a *source* of data for the next block.

Similarly the "sink pad" might be an input but from the other perspective it is also a place where data can be poured into from other blocks.

It is just a matter of changing your perspective on the flow of data to look at it from other units and not the unit you are currently looking at. Where do you as a unit push data to? It certainly wouldn't be a source, I want to push data to a sink somewhere and let them deal with it. I also don't want to pull my data from a sink, I want to get it from a source of data.